# UTF-8 Arabic with HttpServletResponse truncate output

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, utf-8

I have a script that output some XML containing UTF-8 characters.
It works well with latin languages (éàœ,...) but fail when I enter arabic characters: The output is truncated at the first arabic character (ضصيضص).

My code looks like that:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        //...
        res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        res.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        String xml = getXMLString();
        LOG.debug(xml); // Output is correct here 
        op.print(xml);
        op.flush();
        op.close();
}
```

Also, it appears correctly when I display it as HTML

Comment: did you tried using the CDATA to wrap the text ?

Comment: @Mayilarun Nope, but I believe this wouldn't change the outcome: I retrieve the XML with curl, and would be able to see any additional data, even non displayable one. The server output here is clearly truncated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `HttpServletOutputStream` (for binary data), use `PrintWriter` [getWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) of `ServletResponse` that can send character string to client.

```
 res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 res.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
 //now write your text
```

Comment: Good to mention that "setCharacterEncoding" should be called before "getWriter" as in your code otherwise it won't work